# Flexboxes won't stay the correct height when I add in some cross-fading images

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transitions

I need a little help with responsive CSS (flex boxes), and images that I need to rotate using only CSS.

I have created two pens so you can see my problem.

The first is similar to how I want the final product to look, and what is running on my current site.  The flexboxes are responsive and resizing properly, and the pictures and background image/colors are where I want them, and the text is centering vertically and horizontally as it should.

https://codepen.io/hmhaley/pen/xMBvJo

Here's the HTML that's working as expected (though I probably have extra layers of divs I don't need):

```
<div class="boxTable">
    <div class="boxBody">
        <div class="boxRow">

            <div class="boxCell firstBox">
                <div class="boxImage"><img class="bottom" src="https://www.thereconnection.com/sites/default/files/PalmSping_page_slider_1.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="boxCell secondBox">
                <div class="boxText" style="color: #ffffff; background-image: url(https://www.thereconnection.com/sites/default/files/ps_f4/ps_f4/background.jpg);">
                    <div class="textFormat">EXPAND YOUR POSSIBILITIES
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="boxCell thirdBox">
                <div class="boxText" style="color: #ffffff; background-color: #ffffff;">
                    <div class="textFormat" style="color: #999999">ACHIEVE A HIGHER LEVEL OF CONNECTION WITH OTHERS
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="boxCell fourthBox"><img src="https://www.thereconnection.com/sites/default/files/PalmSping_page_slider_2-f1.png">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS that's working that goes with the HTML above (though I may have some extra classes I don't need):

```
body {
    background-color: white;
}

.boxTable {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.boxBody {
    display: table-row-group;
}

.boxRow {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.boxCell {
    border: 0px solid #999999;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    width: 50%;
}

.boxCell img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
}

.boxText {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.textFormat {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2vw;
}
```

Then my boss asked that each image cross-fade on a timer, so that two different pictures rotate back and forth in every other box.  I got that feature to successfully work, but then it messes up my responsive flexboxes.  I can't figure out how to do both together.  I would use Javascript, and try it that way... but we do not have access to add javascript scripts inside our CMS right now (Drupal).  So, I need to make this happen with only CSS/HTML.

https://codepen.io/hmhaley/pen/WPmVyX

Here's the HTML for what's not working (the boxes are not lining-up/stretching/responding as before, though the fade is working):

```
<div class="boxTable">
    <div class="boxBody">
        <div class="boxRow">

            <div class="boxCell firstBox">
                <div class="boxImage"><img class="bottom" src="https://www.thereconnection.com/sites/default/files/PalmSping_page_slider_1.jpg"><img class="top" src="https://www.thereconnection.com/sites/default/files/PalmSping_page_slider_2-f1.png"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="boxCell secondBox">
                <div class="boxText" style="color: #ffffff; background-image: url(https://www.thereconnection.com/sites/default/files/ps_f4/ps_f4/background.jpg);">
                    <div class="textFormat">EXPAND YOUR POSSIBILITIES
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="boxCell thirdBox">
                <div class="boxText" style="color: #ffffff; background-color: #ffffff;">
                    <div class="textFormat" style="color: #999999">BECOME CERTIFIED IN RECONNECTIVE HEALING®
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="boxCell firstBox">
                <div class="boxImage"><img class="bottom" src="https://www.thereconnection.com/sites/default/files/PalmSping_page_slider_2-f1.png"><img class="top" src="https://www.thereconnection.com/sites/default/files/PalmSping_page_slider_1.jpg"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the matching CSS for what's not working that goes with the HTML above:

```
body {
    background-color: white;
}

.boxTable {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.boxBody {
    display: table-row-group;
}

.boxRow {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.boxCell {
    border: 0px solid #999999;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    width: 50%;
}

.boxCell img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
}

.boxText {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.textFormat {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2vw;
}

.boxImage {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.boxImage img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
}

.boxImage > img.top {
animation-name: fade;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 5s;
animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
  opacity:1;
}
25% {
opacity:1;
}
75% {
opacity:0;
}
100% {
opacity:0;
}
}
```

Can someone help me figure out what changes to make to the CSS to have these boxes maintain their size/height, and responsiveness (like on the first codepen), but have the pictures crossfade in and out (like on the second codepen)?

I'm only a baby coder, and more of a Sr product manager and operations guy in real-life, so this has been kicking my butt for days.  I just can't figure it out at this point, and I need to give up and ask for a little help. The pens above are just a sample of the code I'm using on a fairly complex single-page "landing page" with a lot of different formats... but it's the section of that page I am struggling with... so, I've pulled it out and re-created it in codepen for the sake of getting some help. It's my first post on StackOverflow so, go easy on me if I'm not posting this properly. :-)

And, thank you, in advance, to anyone that has a few minutes to look at this and give some advice.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [slick_slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to make this. 
Also I have attached `slick-theme.min.css` , `slick.min.css` , `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` and `slick.min.js`

I hope this will help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.boxImage').slick({
      dots: false,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 2000,
      autoplaySpeed:2000,
      fade: true,
      cssEase: 'linear',
      autoplay: true,
      arrows:false,
      pauseOnFocus:false,
      pauseOnHover:false
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
}

.boxTable {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
}

.boxBody {
 display: table-row-group;
}

.boxRow {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 200px;
}

.boxCell {
 border: 0px solid #999999;
 padding: 0px 0px;
 width: 50%;
}

.boxCell img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 display: flex;
  display: block !important;
}

.boxText {
 display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.textFormat {
 margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2vw;
}

.boxImage {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="boxTable">
    <div class="boxBody">
      <div class="boxRow">
        
        <div class="boxCell firstBox">
          <div class="boxImage slide-one">
             <img class="bottom" src="https://www.thereconnection.com/sites/default/files/PalmSping_page_slider_1.jpg">
            <img class="top" src="https://www.thereconnection.com/sites/default/files/PalmSping_page_slider_2-f1.png">
            
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="boxCell">
          <div class="boxText" style="color: #ffffff; background-image: url(https://www.thereconnection.com/sites/default/files/ps_f4/ps_f4/background.jpg);">
            <div class="textFormat">EXPAND YOUR POSSIBILITIES
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="boxCell thirdBox">
          <div class="boxText" style="color: #ffffff; background-color: #ffffff;">
            <div class="textFormat" style="color: #999999">BECOME CERTIFIED IN RECONNECTIVE HEALING®
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="boxCell firstBox">
          <div class="boxImage">
            <img class="bottom" src="https://www.thereconnection.com/sites/default/files/PalmSping_page_slider_2-f1.png">
            <img class="top" src="https://www.thereconnection.com/sites/default/files/PalmSping_page_slider_1.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for that try... but unfortunately it doesn't seem that this is responsive.  When I try to scale the width of the window, the boxes don't resize and remain 50% of the horizontal page.  :-(

Comment: You need to make it responsive... responsive design not automatically apply.

Comment: @Mar-T-Love  where you resize this window? on stack overflow?

Comment: The original code that I started with was already perfectly responsive (see my first codepen). Then when I tried to add the changing images the boxes stopped being the correct sizes (second codepen). That is what I was trying to understand - why did the perfect size of my boxes go away just because the images are changing.  With your code... you got the boxes to be the correct size again, but you lost the responsiveness I had already achieved in the process.

Comment: I tried resizing the window both on stackexchange ('run code snippet' full screen), and I also transferred your code to a third codepen, and it wasn't responsive there either: [third codepen with your code](https://codepen.io/hmhaley/pen/omRYxg)